# Copy file from NSBundle to Documents error

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I want to copy file from app NSBundle to Documents directory.

How ever i can't get this code working:

```
-(NSString*)copyFile:(NSString*)name{


    NSString *storePath = [[[appDelegate applicationDocumentsDirectory] absoluteString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

    NSError *error;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recordTest" ofType:@"caf"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:defaultStorePath]) {
                [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:&error];
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@)" , [error localizedDescription]);
            }


        }
    }
    return storePath;
}
```

This print The operation couldn’t be completed.

In more detail:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0xd629530 {NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/D0183043-3FD2-4341-8DA4-E1D140E556F6/test.app/recordTest.caf, NSDestinationFilePath=file:/localhost/var/mobile/Applications/D0183043-3FD2-4641-8DA4-E5D140E556F6/Documents/recordTest.caf, NSUnderlyingError=0xd629970 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

I don't get why there are No such file if i check before copying.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your destination is a file URL, not a file path. I always use:

```
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject;
NSString *documentFullPath = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
```

Or, in Swift 2:

```
let documents = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
let fileURL = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)
let documentsFullPath = fileURL.path
```

Answer (score 1):

"storePath" appears to be a URL not a string "path". Add some logs - I suspect you do not want "absoluteString" but "path".